# How to get Cinnamon working in Virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox, cinnamon

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 (32-bit) in VirtualBox 4.1.8.

I wanted to install Cinnamon, so I did and I have the option to choose it from the login screen, as well as GNOME options.

If I choose Ubuntu I get Unity, which works fine. GNOME also works. But when I choose Cinnamon, the screen goes black and nothing responds and I have to reset the virtual machine.

I have already installed Ubuntu 11.10 (64-bit) onto the PC in a separate partition (currently running 10.10 but trying out 11.10) and in that Cinnamon works perfectly. In VirtualBox I have 3D settings enabled and gave the virtual machine 128 MB graphics RAM, and 1024 MB system RAM.

What settings should I change or what should I do to get Cinnamon working in Ubuntu in VirtualBox?

I have also tried doing it in LinuxMint 12, but I get the same problem, just a black screen when selecting Cinnamon.

So are Cinnamon and VirtualBox incompatible?

Comment: what is your host graphics card (`lspci | grep VGA`) and are you using any graphics drivers?

Comment: Are you using the FGLRX/AMD/ATI drivers?

Comment: Have you actually installed the **Guest Additions**?

Comment: Since you're working with VirtualBox anyway, wouldn't it be easier to install LinuxMint directly on its own VirtualBox instance?

Comment: @kavoura - I note you have edited your question by adding a ?.  Please edit your question with the answers above.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The forums suggest this isn't [possible as of now](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=208&t=101296):

> Cinnamon doesn't run inside VirtualBox yet; version 1.5 will, but that is version 1.5
>
> For now, you are stuck with Mate or Gnome Shell (I suggest you to Update Mate to version 1.4; it is *way* better than Gnome shell) and wait for Mint 13 to come out since Maya will have fixed Cinnamon to work with VirtualBox. Nothing to do until then. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 3):

To run Cinnamon in VirtualBox on Windows, I've had to check the PAE/NX in Processor tab in System settings.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks.  Enabling PAE/NX allowed my ISO to boot and then enabling 3D acceleration prevented Cinnamon from crashing see @user65892 's answer below: http://askubuntu.com/a/162894/85213

Comment: I had the same problem running Linux Mint cinnamon on Linux host and this solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Cinnamon works (assuming your hardware isn't the issue). Go to the Display section under Guest OS Settings, and enable 3D Acceleration.

Comment: still doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old but I ran into this issue and fixed it by logging out in terminal  $gnome-session-quit and then selecting cinnamon in the log in page.